# With Netty 4, how do I handle reference counted objects when an exception is thrown inside a handler?

Tags: java, netty

Suppose I have an inbound channel handler like this:

```
public class Handler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    protected void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {                                                                                                                                                                                    
        // msg is actually a reference counted object                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {                                                                                                                                                                              
        // Handle exception here, can't release msg since it's not passed.                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Since `exceptionCaught` does not receive the inbound message in its signature, it seems like there is no way to ensure that the reference counted object is released. It appears that I am forced to wrap the entire contents of `channelRead` in a try/catch block in order to make sure I can recover for any exceptions properly without terminating the entire process. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should release your reference counted objects inside the a try-finally, as shown by the [Netty quick start tutorial](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#looking-into-the-received-data).

This can be done as follows:

```
public class Handler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    protected void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {                                                                                                                                                                                    
        try {
            // msg is actually a reference counted object 
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {                                                                                                                                                                              
        // Handle exception here, can't release msg since it's not passed.                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Notice that I have called `ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);` instead of just `msg.release()`, this is because the fact that calling the first automatically checks if the object in question can be released, while for the latter you need to cast the object to a different type, before you can call the release method.

Comment: Right, but if I have to wrap by whole `channelRead()` method in a try/finally, what's the point of `exceptionCaught()`? Catching exceptions that propagate up? Catching exceptions from other handler methods that don't have the requirement that reference counted items must be released?

Comment: `exceptionCaught` is the central point for any exceptions, not only the exceptions from `channelRead` go to it, but also exceptions thrown in other methods of your handler like `channelWrite`, or even exceptions from other handlers. You can even configure netty to throw any low level NIO exceptions during writing into the exception caugth. Alternatively, you could extend  `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` instead of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` and it will close the reference counted object for you

Comment: Thanks again, by the way. Sorry I didn't vote up too, earlier :)